# error: Command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1. pip3 install openpiv

Tags: python

I tried to install openpiv for python3 in macOS Catalina whith

```
pip3 install openpiv
```

and in time to install scikit-image show this:

```
Running setup.py install for scikit-image ... error
```

and then show this:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
```

I tried to do what other similar questions do, but it doesn't work. Help!!

Comment: Can you please add, what have you tired as of now.

Comment: I use `xcode-select --install. In a post they said: reinstall your Xcode Command Line Tools after upgrading to Catalina.

Comment: then show this: xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates.
and I use softwareupdate --install -a